# How do I compose a  Gmail message with an attachment from a URL?

Tags: ruby, url, gmail, attachment

I am writing a little script in Ruby that searches for a file in a directory and creates a new Gmail message to send. It should have the name of the file in the subject field, and the file as an attachment.

I have this URL http://pastie.org/3240209 which gets me to the compose page of Gmail, and fills the subject with the name of a PDF file.

I want to add this file as an attachment. Can I do that somehow through the URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to send something with gmail, you should not be doing it that way.  Google exposes gmail through standard IMAP and SMTP.  You can use oauth to connect to these services in ruby.  See http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/.  You can use oauth along with the ruby standard SMTP library to send gmail then.

Comment: yes, i know there are better ways, but i really want the autocompletion of the recipient field..

Comment: Then you should perhaps implement it yourself with jquery and fetch contacts from http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html.  Google handles attachments in gmail with a ton of javascript magic that may be very difficult to get going programmatically.